# 20-Questions on a grid

Tags: mathematics, algorithm

[<sup>*Posted this on /r/puzzles too, none have given the right strategy as of now :)*</sup>](https://www.reddit.com/r/puzzles/comments/952p31/a_20questionsesque_puzzle_to_find_a_cell_in_a_grid/)

There is a square grid of width and height $m$. Three facts about the grid:

1. Each cell has a value, and no two cells have the same value.
2. Each row and column is either ascending or descending.
3. $1 \le m \le 1000$

You have to find some value v in the grid, (or see if it exists in the grid or not). What you can do: Ask an oracle for the value in a particular cell. But you can only ask a maximum of $4\times m$ questions to the oracle. What's your strategy?

For an easier version, try to solve it with around $m. \log(m)$ questions.

Best of luck!

<sup>Also, $4\times m$ doesn't *necessarily* mean that the puzzle can be solved in $4\times m$ questions for all $m > 1000$ ;)</sup>

PS: Row $i$ can be ascending, row $j$ can be descending, column $a$ can be ascending, $b$ can be descending etc, the entire grid isn't sorted, the rows and columns have their individual sorting.

Comment: For example, if m is equal to 3, we can ask 12 questions, though there are 9 grids. you will find v or not for sure...  I think m is meant to be greater than some value like 4?

Comment: Is the strategy the same for odd and even values of $m$ ?
Because I want to ask for the two diagonals, but this fails when $m$ is odd I think

Comment: @Oray The constraint on m is given, it can be upto 1000

Comment: @FlorianBourse Hmm, my approach with some change works for odd too. Post your idea for even below, I'll check it out :) (I'm OP btw, stupidly posted the question on a guest account)

Comment: @four_lines you can [merge accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18233)

Comment: @Kruga it's not working since the guest account isn't recognized as an actual profile for some reason :/

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer (the idea to solve it by $O(M~log(M))$):

> You may try to find the value *independently* for each row (or column). What you have to do is to use [Binary Search Algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) -- like to find a word in a dictionary -- on each row.

Comment: Right :) Now try for the harder version!

Answer (score 2):

Edit: There's a flaw in the answer below as pointed out in the comments, I will leave this here because some ideas might help other people (then again, maybe I'm on the wrong way)

I think the following strategy works, might be slightly off with roundings, but would probably be ok for m a power of 2:

> First, query all the elements on both diagonals. This takes $2m$ queries, and is the fastest way to determine all the ordering in each row/column.
>  This restricts the value you're looking for in at most one of the 4  triangular quadrants defined by the 2 diagonals: up/left/right/bottom.
>  You're left with $2m$ queries and have to search in a triangle of basis $m-2$, and height $(m-2)/2$.
>  Then, we finish by an easy induction / binary search. We can cut the triangle in half with $(m-2)/2$, and have a rectangle triangle that you can cut with only $(m-2)/4$ queries. Then you're left with a triangle that is identical, but $4$ times smaller than the previous one, and repeat.
>  The cost in query of this induction is thus $\sum_i (m-2)/2^i$, which is less than $2m$

Comment: How can you determine the quadrant where the value resides?

Comment: @wl pointed out a major flaw in your answer. Figuring out the ordering of each row and column isn't enough to tell in what row, column or quadrant the value is. For example, if you have: line1=`1 ? 9`, line2=`? 4 ?` and line3=`11 ? 2`, the number 3 can be on any exclamation mark (or absent).

Comment: You're right, I was thinking on each row you'd end up with being either left middle or right, and the columns would help solving, but there are in fact possibilities where the number could be in any spot
Another example that kills this strategy is a grid that is symmetric along both diagonals. I edited the answer to reflect the fact that it is flawed

Answer (score 1):

I show a solution for

> $m \in \{5,6\}$, that is the smallest $m$s where allowed number of questions ($4\times m$) is less than the number of cells.

First,

> query the $2\times m$ cells on the main diagonal and another 'parallel' translated diagonal which starts in the $\lceil\frac{m+2}2\rceil$th column, so the queried diagonals are as far from each other as possible.
>  This way, we will have 2 queried cells in each row, and the rest of the $m-2$ cells in the row are divided into 2 or 3 groups, where the largest group's size is $\lceil\frac{m-2}2\rceil$.
>  As $m\le6$, $\lceil\frac{m-2}2\rceil\le2$, so even if we have to check all the $\lceil\frac{m-2}2\rceil$ cells in each of the $m$ rows, we don't exceed the limitation of $4\times m$ questions.

Please notice that

> the restriction for the columns wasn't even utilised, and that the strategy wasn't really adaptive: which values to ask from the oracle wasn't depending on the previous answer for the first $2\times m$ cells at all. I have the intuition, that in a typical case the monotonity criteria coming from the columns gives another factor of $\frac12$ on the size of the groups, so $m\le10$ can be solved.

Answer (score 1):

**The General Answer**

First of all, we need to consider odd dimension grids and even dimension grids separately. Because their solution is close but separate.

Let's start with odd dimension one: 5x5

> [image]

This is

> The first numbers you need to ask for, because you would know the biggest and the smallest value in the grid. Even cells are easier in my option.

Then

> you may even be able to eliminate some cells which would not be having the number you are looking for. But if you are unlucky, you may not if our number is in between all those values. For example, if $A=100$, $B=1$, $C=12$ and $D=50$, and the number you are looking for $27$, you will not able to eliminate any cell for this moment.

Let's guess

> other corner values in the inner square

shown below:

> [image]

This is better guess because you will able to eliminate some cells for sure now because

> If our number is in between E-F you will able to eliminate first and last cells on the second column, if our number is greater/smaller than F and smaller/greater than E, we can eliminate two cells. So whatever our number is, we can eliminate two cells from the grid. For example let's say our number is $27$, $E$ is 20 and $F$ is $10$, then you can eliminate two cells etc. Likewise, we can eliminate two more cells from the second row which is not common with the column, (I will call it E-H column) Likewise on the H-G column and F-G row, we can eliminate another 4 cells whatever number we have!

So ,

> [image]

So for example, one of the worst case is

> [image]

Note that the red cells are the cells where our number cannot be there.

> So only asking 4 more cells shown below, will eliminate another 4 cells with

the same logic above, asking for I,K,L,J will guarantee that 2 white cells left:

> [image]

So

> in total for 5x5, 15 cell asking guarantee to find or not your number exists. This is optimal solution for 5x5! Even if you asked for every white cells left, it would be sufficient for $4m$,

Here is why:

> In general You need to ask diagonal values first, then eliminate all cells when possible, then ask for cells not to next to each other in a row or column, and eliminate accordingly. When the dimension increases, elimination number of cell you can eliminate is getting bigger, for example for 5x5, you can eliminate $8$ cells in this process, but for 7x7, you can eliminate $8+16$ cells in total.

In general, you can eliminate

> $4\left (\frac{m-1}{2}-1  \right )\left (\frac{m-1}{2}\right )=m^2-4m+3$

so you asked for

> $2(m-1)$ cells,

and

> eliminated $m^2-4m+3$ out of $m^2$ cells

and white cell count becomes

> $m^2-(m^2-4m+3)-(2m-2)=2m-1$

so we asked for

> $2m-2$ and $2m-1$ cells left. If we ask all cells one by one, $4m-3$ cells would be asked which is smaller than $4m$.

As shown below (11x11):

> [image]

And for the rest of while cells,

> $2(m-1)$ diagonal cell asking + even you dont have to, asking the rest of while cells which is $2m-1$ is sufficient to have smaller than $4m$. For your information, asking all white cells left is not optimal, but as I said it is sufficient to have less than $4m$.

Comment: How does this work when the original uncovered corners are: top left 1, top right 21, bottom left 25, bottom right 11? Supposing we are looking for value 12, no cells can be excluded directly in this case I think.

Comment: The problem does not state that the numbers are integers, so how about this:
1,13,19,20,21;22,21.5,20.5,19.5,18;23,22.5,21.6,18.6,17;24,23.5,22.6,17.6,16;25,24.5,24.4,12,11

Comment: I'm not sure I get your notation right. Shouldn't the top-row second cell be black on the picture you posted in your comment?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think you are on track, or at least your idea/method is the best so far. I just wanted to note that you seem to work with some hypotheses that were not true. Keep up the good work!

Comment: @elias Oops the problem was supposed to only be for integers, my bad for not mentioning (though maybe someone could extend the solution to something general). Also Oray you're on the right track :)

Comment: @four_lines, even if it is about integers, do we know, that those are the integers in the range of 1 to m^2? Otherwise just multiply my numbers with 10.

Comment: @elias An upperbound of $10^9$ or $10^{10}$ is a good range. Setting it to $m^2$ might make it easier.

Comment: Counterexample for the even case: let's say, that instead of 40, we have 25, and instead of 90 we have 26 in the given cells. This adds four more white cells, and increases the sum over $4m$, doesn't it?

Comment: Similarly for the odd case: if there is 30 instead of 10, 29 instead of 4 and 28 instead of 5, we get 10 more white cells, 29 in total, which is more than 4x7. Am I missing something?

Comment: @elias the even one is not counter example, check how many red grid has been spotted. https://ibb.co/dH9ZFe let me check odd one. it is even less than 4m-4, 19 guess will be enough since 3 grid next to each other. let me check odd one too

Comment: @elias, for odd case, that's not possible case, because between 80-29 it has to be greater than 25 (middle one) so we know that between 30-60 it should be less than 25, which is impossible.

Comment: @Oray, seems you are right. But I still don't see how your examples are proving a general case.

Comment: @elias  well i never said this is kinda proof but i am 100% sure this is the way of how to solve it. though i dont have %100 proof here at all. i will try to make it more understandable at least, it is not easy to show the proof to be honest.

Comment: @elias  that example is the worst case possible conditions. did wrote a program which generates all possible descending ascending in rows/columns, and try to find all numbers exist with the simple algorithm above. it seems working tough no proof :/

Comment: How did you calculate the number of white grids left to guess? (I'm still trying to understand the even case) Let's say my grid is always ascending such that biggest is bottom right, wouldn't the (m/2)² bottom right squares be left white in some cases?

Comment: @FlorianBourse I edited the question from the very beginning :D

Comment: @elias could you check my last edit please, this is kinda proof in my opinion!

Comment: I don't think the "worst cases" you present in your answer are actually worst cases. What if the remaining possibilities aren't all in a single cross? Say, they're all in one of the triangular "quadrants" left after you find all the values on the big X -- In fact, we can get possible values in one quadrant, plus one of the "limbs" on the cross. That's a total of (n/2)^2 + n/2 squares left, which is decidedly more than 2n - 1. (edited the math a bit)

Comment: @Persona  it does not matter whether if it is single cross or not, we open all the remaining white squares.

Comment: One such possibility would be the top left "arm" of the big X being all larger than v, bottom left being all smaller; then the top right being even more large, and the bottom left being even more small.

Comment: @Persona i couldnt understand what u mean, give an example please

Comment: Example: Say, on the 11x11 grid, we're looking for 100. An example of the numbers you look at that would leave a larger number of white squares than you expect, listed top to bottom, left to right, like you might read a book: 101, 201, 102, 202, 103, 203, 104, 204, 105, 205, (here's the middle), 99, 89, 98, 88, 97, 87, 96, 86, 95, 85. You should see that this leaves you with 25 + 6 = 31 squares, which is larger than 2n - 1 for m = 11. As I mentioned earlier, this scales as (n/2)^2 + n/2, up to some rounding shenanigans.

Comment: @Persona you cannot have bigger/smaller number inner squares than corner biggest and smallest values technically :) that's why I check corners and inner corners all the time....

Comment: @Oray It's not very hard to change the numbers to make it work again. Pretend the example was 105, 205, 104, 204, 103, 203, 102, 202, 101, 201, (middle here), 99, 89, 98, 88, 97, 87, 96, 86, 95, 85 instead. Almost exactly the same, except with the top half reversed.

Comment: @Oray, I'm afraid I don't understand how you handle all the cases, so I'm not able to check your method. I know it means a lot of work, but if you happen to write a program that solves the problem and take text files as input, I'm happy to contribute with some test cases to verify.

Comment: @persona you seem right, you can simply apply binary search after that which will not take for $4m$+, though my explanation was just opening all white squares but it was brute force way... normally anyone would do binary search after that...

Comment: @Oray Now take my previous example and flip the bottom half horizontally. That is, it's like 105, 205, ... , 101, 201, (middle), 89, 99, ..., 85, 95. Let the middle row (all white squares) be smaller than 100 on the left half, and bigger on the right half -- exact values don't matter. Counting manually, I get a minimum of 20 extra samples, bringing the total to 40 samples needed -- awful close to the max 44. Now, considering that the samples needed to finish grows something like n*log(n), which is faster than linear, you should verify that it still works for larger squares.

Comment: @Persona https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D9RN52hEG2VysrrvzzRnFKLp_G8LyAZU27Mje9GFIVA/edit?usp=sharing please put your numbers here.

Comment: @Oray Have a 17x17 grid for free, too. Remember, worst case, binary searches always put the number you're looking for on the bigger half!